Transfer animation from bones to empty
I have a script to load animations from one game, the animations in it are represented as points and their coordinates. I also have a script to export these points.
To make it easier for me to animate I connected some points to bones, but when animating bones animation animation is not transferred to empty. I tried manually inserting frames, I tried using bake action, but the animation still remains on the skeleton and bones, and when I remove keyframes from the skeleton the points stop moving.


It's not clear what you mean when you say "animation is not transferred to empty". Do you mean it's not moving at all in the viewport, or its not exporting correctly or what? It might be easier for us to get if you could post some gifs/video or if you could share your Blender project file. Instructions for sharing.

It's not clear how did you "Connect" points to bones, and which are points and empties, but generally speaking if you want to keyframe a child object in its world loc rot and scale, you should use "Insert VISUAL Loc Rot Scale Keyframe" operator (use K instead of I to insert a keyframe).
To automate the process, your final empties should have a Copy Transform Constraint targeting some mechanism (a bone or another empty), so that when baking the animation you can select all desired constrained empties and tick the "Visual transform" and "Clear constraints" options, in order to have the animation baked to empties in world space.
